# Как убрать рамки внутри DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Как поменять черные рамки внутри `DataGrid`?
[image: Data Grid рамки]

Если изменять свойства DataGridCell:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 5" />
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
</Style>
```

Получается как то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Короче, нужно просто поменять цвет на серый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно всего лишь задать свойства `VerticalGridLinesBrush` и `HorizontalGridLinesBrush`:

```
<DataGrid VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray">
        //---
</DataGrid>
```